# Tests of within subjects contrasts in R

Tags: r, spss, repeated-measures, contrasts, split-plot

I have run a split splot model in SPSS (via repeated measures function) and I would like to reproduce my results using R. To do so I used ezANOVA function from ez package to obtain sphericity tests and correction and type III SS. I have read that aov function does not give type III SS. So far the results are identical with those from SPSS but I cannot tell so when I run tests of within subjects contrasts. I use polynomial contrasts and my factor has six levels. What I manage to get is t-values instead of f-values or f-values but not the same as in SPSS. Here is my data and code

```
id    subj  treat  m1    m2    m3    m4    m5   m6
1       1     1   455   460   510   504   436   466
2       2     1   467   565   610   596   542   587
3       3     1   445   530   580   597   582   619
4       4     1   485   542   594   583   611   612
5       5     1   480   500   550   528   562   576
6       6     2   514   560   565   524   552   597
7       7     2   440   480   536   484   567   569
8       8     2   495   570   569   585   576   677
9       9     2   520   590   610   637   671   702
10     10     2   503   555   591   605   649   675
11     11     3   496   560   622   622   632   670
12     12     3   498   540   589   557   568   609
13     13     3   478   510   568   555   576   605
14     14     3   545   565   580   601   633   649
15     15     3   472   498   540   524   532   583
```

m1-m6 represent measurements in 6 different time points. My code for the contrasts.

```r
long.df<- melt(data, id=c('subj','treat'))
 long.df<- long.df[order(long.df$subj)]
 names(long.df)<- c('subj','treat','time','meas')
 mod<- lm(meas~time + time^2 + time^3 + time^4 + time^5, long.df)
 summary(mod) # this is how I obtain t-values for the polynomial contrasts #
 mod1<- aov(meas~time + time^2 + time^3 + time^4 + time^5, long.df)
 summary(mod1, split=list(time=list("Linear"=1, "Quad"=2,'q'=3,'f'=4,'fif'=5))) # this is how i obtain f-values #
```

I think that the F-values correspond to type 1 SS (as I use aov function). How am I wrong? Is there a way to conduct the Tests of within subjects contrasts and obtain type III SS so I will have identical results to SPSS? Here are the SPSS results.

```
Source  time    Type III SS/    df/      Mean Square/       F/   Sig.   
time    Linear  123662.881/ 1/  123662.881/ 83.591/ .000    
     Quadratic  5928.007/   1/  5928.007/   18.968/ .001    
    Cubic   10462.676/  1/  10462.676/  28.075/ .000    
    Order 4 798.193  /       1/       798.193/  4.010/  .068    
    Order 5 1702.743/   1/  1702.743/   4.878/  .047
```

Answer (score 1):

aov does use type 1 SS.

You could do something like this (in the car package) instead:

```r
print(Anova(lm(Score~1+A+B+C+A:B+B:C+A:C+A:B:C, data=dat), type="III"))
```

You can change type to "I" or "II" to get the various types of SS.

For more information about how types of SS work, see this [link](http://mcfromnz.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/anova-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/).

Comment: @ Sarah Thomas. Your comment along with the link was very helpful. But, I am still can't understand how am I wrong. You see SPSS uses F-tests in within subjects contrasts tests, especially type III ones. What I am trying to do is reproduce those results using R but I can't figure out how. The code I tried and I mentioned above gives different results from SPSS showing that I am wrong in some way.

Comment: @Manos I'm a bit confused about what you tried. Did you try print(Anova(lm(meas~time + time^2 + time^3 + time^4 + time^5, long.df), type="III"))?

Comment: @ Sarah Thomas. Yes I tried it but I cannot get F tests for every degree of the polynomial separately. I only get the F-test for the whole time effect. My professor told me that I must use lme function (lme4 package) , which I did but I have not managed to get the desired results so far. I am still working on it, if I have sth I will let you know.

Comment: @Manos That's strange, when I run print(Anova(lm(meas~time + time^2 + time^3 + time^4 + time^5, long.df), type="III")) on some data I made up I get an F for each term in the model. Are you sure you used the print function?

Comment: @ Sarah Thomas. The truth is that I did not use print function.Thanks for pointing it out. However, my professor told me that lme function should be used here. I will try with print and I will let you know.